# more eloquent way to use conditional on buttons for angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class, angular-ng-if

right now i'm using an ng-if to determine which button to show my users based on a condition. It just checks if my $scope.method matches the file variable.

```
<a class="btn btn-default" ng-if="method != file" ng-click="change(file)">Upload</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" ng-if="method === file" ng-click="change(file)">Upload</a>
```

however im wondering if there is a more eloquent way to do this by using ng-class or any other angular directives...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. `ng-class` is what you are wanting.

```
<a class="btn" ng-class="{'btn-default': method != file, 'btn-primary': method === file}" 
    ng-if="method != file" ng-click="change(file)">Upload</a>
```

Here is a [fantastic article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass) I always reference when I'm needing to use ng-class.

Answer (score 0):

You shall use ng-class to acheive that and add conditionnal class 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: OP just wants different class based on `method === file`. Click handler doesn't change.

Comment: thank for telling that. I'll update my post with ng-class